# Custom calendar Component

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I need a  Date custom component which is date should be disable when selected the calendar icon.

If any one have pls share me.

Comment: could you explain what you mean?

Comment: A custom Date component in which the date field is disabled - is it?

Comment: Yes Amar, It is correct.

Answer (score 2):

What did you mean?

https://www.flextras.com//index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=15

http://www.keepcore.com/composants-flex/flex-calendar-component.html

http://www.imbizzi.com/

(!) http://forums.adobe.com/message/2887093

http://www.flashenabledblog.com/2007/07/06/interactive-flex-calendar-componentwith-source-just-awesome/

http://www.quietlyscheming.com/blog/components/interactive-calendar/

(!) http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/ibmilogelixir/

Comment: need a simple flex calender with date filed is disabled. I had checked all the above links, some components are not free and some components are not look good.

Comment: maybe it will be better for you to get sources of standard component and extend it with your feature. Don't you?

Comment: am new to flex. So i do not have much idea about that. Please help me.

Comment: are you able to draw some visual draft for me in something like paint, to help me understand what do you exactly want?

Comment: when i select the flex simple calender icon,  i need to disply only month and year Not to display dates.

Comment: select the flex simple calender icon, disable the date and only can select month and year